# how to use serializeRowData option with editRow method in jqgrid to post a json data to server

Tags: jqgrid

how to use serializeRowData option with editRow method in jqgrid to post a json data to server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`serializeRowData` may be used to take a row's data and serialize it to (for example) JSON or XML prior to POSTing it to the server. [Here](http://theapexfreelancer.blogspot.com/2010/01/jqgrid-custom-post-parameters-when.html) is an article that provides an overview of its usage. Basically, here is example code to use it along with json2.js (from json.org) to serialize data to JSON prior to being submitted:

```
jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
 ...
 serializeRowData: function(postdata){
    return { x01: JSON.stringify(postdata) };
 }
 ...
});
```

Does that help?